# How can I write this code as short as possible?

Tags: php, php-7

Can I write this code shorter in PHP7?

```
if(isset($content[$i]['count']))
    $content[$i]['count'] = 1;
else
    $content[$i]['count'] += $content[$i]['count'];
```

Comment: How about you first of all write it _correct_? Right now you are trying to add it to itself when it is _not_ set in the first place - nonsense to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use use a ternary

```
$content[$i]['count'] = isset($content[$i]['count']) ? 0 : += $content[$i]['count'];
```

Which is 3 lines less.

It also depends on your code, as the usual method is to set the initial count to 0, e.g. outside a foreach or whatever, then increment on each loop simply with `$count++;`

I wonder why though, as sometimes code just is what it is, and you should avoid being too terse for the sake of less code as it can make it less obvious or understandable.

Also, seems wrong setting your count to 0 if it's set, this would suggest only 1 count could happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortest possible way is with use of the coalesce operator:

```
$content[$i]['count'] = ($content[$i]['count'] ?? 0.5) * 2;
```

But it seems rather complex to understand quickly. :)